# $X_{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(r)}X_{n}$ is equivalent to $|X_{n}|^{r}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(1)}|X_{n}|$ statement correctness

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm currently reading the book *An Introduction to Measure -Theoretic Probability* by Roussas, George G, and there is this remark in the book (p.111, Remark 7)

> $X_{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(r)}X_{n}$ is equivalent to $|X_{n}|^{r}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(1)}|X_{n}|^{r}$

Here the notation $X_{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(r)}X$ denotes $X_{n}$ converges in the rth mean to $X$, i.e, $E[|X_{n}-X|^{r}]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.

---

Now suppose $X_{n} = -1$ for all $n$ and $X=1$. Then $|X_{n}|^{r} = |X|^{r} = 1$ for all $n$. Thus $|X_{n}|^{r}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(1)}|X_{n}|^{r}$. But $E[|X_{n}-X|^{r}] = E[2^{r}] = 2^{r}$ does not converge to 0, therefore $X_{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(r)}X_{n}$ cannot be true.

---

Is this statement wrong? Or am I missing something? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your counter-example is correct. The statement would be true, however, if the $X_n$ are positive (maybe this is the case in the context of this remark ?) In the general case, you only have that the direct implication ; the reverse would also be true if you add absolute values around $X_n$ and $X$ (typo ?)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in Remark 7 is that $|X_n|^r\xrightarrow{p}|X|^r$ does not imply that $X_n\xrightarrow{p}X$. Just take $X_n=-X$ for each $n\ge 1$ with $\mathsf{P}(X\ne 0) >0$. Therefore, one cannot use Theorem 14 to conclude.

Comment: That was the point where I got confused. So I guess the author made a mistake?

Comment: @cici30725 Indeed, it's a mistake.